# Throwing 'MobXException' when i am updating mobX State and updating in view with Observer

Tags: dart, flutter, mobx

I am trying the mobX State management for flutter. But whenever I am updating my **@observable State** directly rather than calling an **@action decorated method** it is  throwing **'MobXException'**

Below code will will give you a proper idea.

**counter.dart**

```dart
import 'package:mobx/mobx.dart';

part 'counter.g.dart';

class Counter = CounterBase with _$Counter;

abstract class CounterBase implements Store {
  @observable
  int value = 0;

  @action
  void increment() {
    value++;
  }
}
```

**main.dart**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_mobx/flutter_mobx.dart';
import './counter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Counter",
      home: CounterExample(),
    );
  }
}

class CounterExample extends StatelessWidget {
  final _counter = Counter();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Counter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Observer(
              builder: (_) => Text(
                    '${_counter.value}',
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
                  )),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // _counter.increment(); // WORKING !!
            _counter.value = _counter.value+1; // NOT WORKING !!
          },
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      );
}
```

using the increment method is working but why even for some simple state change I need to make another method? why the generated setter is not sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But whenever I am updating my @observable State directly rather than calling an @action decorated method it is throwing 'MobXException'

That's a feature. MobX purposefully prevents you from mutating observables outside of an *action*.

Move that logic in a method of your store instead.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the clarification. can you recommend some state management library which I can use for small apps and does not need much boilerplate code? mobX is good but every time I make any change in the store class i need to run the build runner to generate all the methods. which is taking like 20 seconds of time every time.\

Comment: Report that as an issue. Mobx isn't that slow to generate in my experience